# Why wont my server start

Tags: tomcat, ruby

I'm having real difficulty with a server on our load balance cluster and cant understand why. In the catalina log the following appears. It had been another site before and I removed it to see if that was the problem but now its a different site.

```
12-Nov-2015 16:52:13.839 INFO [secure.enterprisecreditunion.org-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log INFO: using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
12-Nov-2015 16:52:32.492 INFO [secure.enterprisecreditunion.org-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup
Permission denied - /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log
--- System
jruby 1.7.18 (1.9.3p551) 2014-12-22 625381c on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_75-b13 +jit [linux-amd64]
Time: 2015-11-12 16:52:32 +0000
Server: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
jruby.home: file:/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home

--- Context Init Parameters:
jruby.compat.version = 1.9
public.root = /
rack.env = production

--- Backtrace
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log
          mkdir at org/jruby/RubyDir.java:443
       fu_mkdir at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:247
        mkdir_p at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:221
   reverse_each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1693
        mkdir_p at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:219
           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
        mkdir_p at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:205
         setup! at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:305
         logger at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:278
         logger at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:16
          load! at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/loader.rb:55
         (root) at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/config/boot.rb:8
        require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071
         (root) at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
        require at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
  instance_eval at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1533
         (root) at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/config.ru:5
     initialize at /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55

--- RubyGems
Gem.dir: /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems
Gem.path:
/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems
Activated gems:
  rack-1.5.2
  bundler-1.9.2
  rake-10.4.2
  i18n-0.7.0
  json-1.8.2-java
  minitest-5.6.0
  thread_safe-0.3.5-java
  tzinfo-1.2.2
  activesupport-4.2.1
  bcrypt-3.1.10-java
  colorize-0.7.7
  net-ssh-2.9.2
  net-scp-1.2.1
  sshkit-1.7.1
  capistrano-3.0.1
  capistrano-bundler-1.1.2
  capistrano-rbenv-2.0.1
  ffi-1.9.8-java
  childprocess-0.5.6
  choice-0.2.0
  dbd-jdbc-0.1.6-java
  pdf-core-0.2.5
  ttfunk-1.2.2
  prawn-1.2.1
  dberkom-sinatra-prawn-0.9.2.2
  deprecated-2.0.1
  dbi-0.4.5
  tilt-1.4.1
  haml-4.0.6
  url_mount-0.2.1
  http_router-0.11.1
  iso_country_codes-0.6.1
  jdbc-jtds-1.3.0.1
  jruby-jars-1.7.15
  jruby-openssl-0.9.7-java
  mime-types-1.25.1
  polyglot-0.3.5
  treetop-1.4.15
  mail-2.5.4
  mizuno-0.6.9
  moneta-0.7.20
  multipart-post-2.0.0
  padrino-support-0.12.5
  rack-protection-1.5.3
  sinatra-1.4.6
  thor-0.19.1
  padrino-core-0.12.5
  padrino-helpers-0.12.5
  padrino-admin-0.12.5
  padrino-cache-0.12.5
  padrino-gen-0.12.5
  padrino-mailer-0.12.5
  padrino-0.12.5
  padrino-flash-0.2.0
  pdfkit-0.8.2
  prawn-table-0.1.2
  rubyzip-0.9.9
  sass-3.4.13
  sinatra-flash-0.3.0

--- Bundler
Bundler.bundle_path: /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems
Bundler.root: /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF
Gemfile: /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/Gemfile
Settings:
  gemfile = /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/Gemfile
  without = development:test:assets
  bin_path = /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.9.2/bin/bundle

--- JRuby-Rack Config
compat_version = RUBY1_9
default_logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.StandardOutLogger@1c8dbd49
equals = <error: >
err = org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler@78b1d3
filter_adds_html = true
filter_verifies_resource = false
ignore_environment = false
initial_memory_buffer_size =
initial_runtimes =
jms_connection_factory =
jms_jndi_properties =
logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.ServletContextLogger@3bf8b26a
logger_class_name = servlet_context
logger_name = jruby.rack
maximum_memory_buffer_size =
maximum_runtimes =
num_initializer_threads =
out = org.apache.tomcat.util.log.SystemLogHandler@64c50834
rackup =
rackup_path =
rewindable = true
runtime_arguments =
runtime_environment =
runtime_timeout_seconds =
serial_initialization = false
servlet_context = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@75d74400
throw_init_exception = false

12-Nov-2015 16:52:32.493 SEVERE [secure.enterprisecreditunion.org-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ERROR: initialization failed
 org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: Permission denied - /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log
        from org/jruby/RubyDir.java:443:in `mkdir'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:221:in `mkdir_p'
        from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1693:in `reverse_each'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:219:in `mkdir_p'
        from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:305:in `setup!'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:278:in `logger'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:16:in `logger'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/loader.rb:55:in `load!'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/config/boot.rb:8:in `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071:in `require'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1533:in `instance_eval'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/config.ru:5:in `(root)'
        from /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'

        at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:104)
        at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (EACCES) Permission denied - /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log
        at org.jruby.RubyDir.mkdir(org/jruby/RubyDir.java:443)
        at RUBY.fu_mkdir(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:247)
        at RUBY.mkdir_p(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:221)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.reverse_each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1693)
        at RUBY.mkdir_p(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:219)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
        at RUBY.mkdir_p(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:205)
        at RUBY.setup!(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:305)
        at RUBY.logger(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:278)
        at RUBY.logger(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:16)
        at RUBY.load!(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.5/lib/padrino-core/loader.rb:55)
        at RUBY.(root)(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/config/boot.rb:8)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071)
        at RUBY.(root)(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1)
        at RUBY.require(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.18.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.instance_eval(org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1533)
        at RUBY.(root)(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/config.ru:5)
        at RUBY.initialize(/var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55)

12-Nov-2015 16:52:32.503 SEVERE [secure.enterprisecreditunion.org-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /var/lib/tomcat8/work/Catalina/secure.enterprisecreditunion.org/ROOT is unusable.
```

Comment: Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log

Comment: Maybe you removed this folder and it is no more existing, or you don't have enought rights to write into it

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's your question exactly? And why did you stop in the middle of describing the problem? (Does the file referred to in the error message exist? What are its permissions? Etcetera.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Permission denied - /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log

and

> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log

I would work on clearing those first. Who knows it may solve the problem.

Perhaps

```
mkdir -p  /var/lib/tomcat8/enterprise/ROOT/WEB-INF/log
```

would be a place to start

Comment: this answer has already been given in comment

Comment: @Froggiz - it's not an answer then is it. Comments are for erm comments, answers are for answers

Comment: Cheers to Iain and Froggiz for the help. It was a case of accidentally restarting tomcat as root which meant all files were ownder by root rather than tomcat user. Anyway hope it hasnt caused too much bother.